# How to show the result of application.vlookup function as TextBox.Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I´m creating a Userform that among other things displays the name of employee when the ID field is completed.

In TextBox1 the user enters the ID and in TextBox4 they will see their names.

The problem comes because I´m using Application.Vlookup to complete TextBox4.

I´m not sure where is the error here.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngvlook As Range
    Dim val As String, result As Variant

    Set rngvlook = Hoja3.Range("A:B")
    val = TextBox1.Value
    result = Application.VLookup(val, rngvlook, 2, False)

        If IsError(result) Then
            TextBox4.Value = ""
        Else
            TextBox4.Value = result
        End If
End Sub
```

Bellow the error

Error '-2147352571 (80020005) on execution time

Value property can´t be set. Type mismatch

Comment: "The problem comes" - which problem? "I´m not sure where is the error here." Neither am I! You haven't described an error.

Comment: A problem with the change event is that it will fire every time you press a key so I would assign to a button or another event.

Comment: Or you can place the code in the `textbox1_exit` event

Comment: Sorry, I´m new here. I just added the error message from VBA. @SJR

Comment: Textbox.text not value

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner . Your input solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in a way an "architecture" error. Take a look at this VLookups with the following input in `Range("A:B")`:

[image]

The following code returns probabaly something unexpected:

```
Sub SomeTest()

    'Runs ok:
    Debug.Print Application.VLookup(1, Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    Debug.Print Application.VLookup("id1", Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    Dim val1 As Variant: val1 = 1
    Debug.Print Application.VLookup(val1, Range("A:B"), 2, False)

    'Error 2042:
    Debug.Print Application.VLookup("1", Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    Dim val2 As String: val2 = 1
    Debug.Print Application.VLookup(val2, Range("A:B"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Thus, in your code, you go into the second part of the example, thus going to Error 2042. Try to "move" your code to the working sample, thus declare the `val` as a `Variant`.